# Rails 4.2.1 - Very slow image assets on AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which makes and AJAX call to load some content. That triggers this JS:

```
$('#load_search').fadeIn().html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'products/search')}");
```

In products/search I have a simple loop:

```
- @products.each do |product|
   %h1= product.name
   = image_tag product.image_url
```

The AJAX call takes about 8 seconds to load 24 products! If I remove the image_tag it is done in 300ms. Why is it taking 8 seconds? Is that because the assets needs to be loaded before the ajax call can complete?

Comment: How big are your image files?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the times in your rails log, and also in the Net tab of firebug. That should give you a sense of whether most of the time is in fetching the images, or transmitting them over the net, etc.

I used to render partials in ajax requests like that, but now I'm moving towards using backbone and rendering the records in a handlebars (clientside JS) template instead. You might find that approach helpful, both for performance and to keep javascript and ruby from getting mixed up with each other.

Comment: I am using the Rails console and Chrome developer . Rails console tells it takes 8 s for views and I found out that is because of the image_tag in the partial. It still does not explain why.

Comment: I am not looking for a solution to render fast, but an answers that can explain why it does 8 s with the image_tag. I have solution with a JS template where the ajax call only request JSON.

Comment: does the JSON response include product.image_url for each product? Anything else happening in products/search that would account for it?

Comment: It is not a JSON response my example is a HTML response. I just said I have a solution to this problem by using a JSON response instead with a JS template to render the HTML.

Comment: It is properly because Rails in development mode Precompiles all assets on the fly